# Cutting a vector in R into intervals using breaks from another vector

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors vec1 and vec2.

```
vec1 <- c(0:10)
vec2<- c(-5:12)
```

I want to use the breaks from vector 1 and apply them to vector 2 with a value less than the minimum point of the lowest breakpoint being assigned to the lowest quantile while those greater than the maximum point of the breakpoint being assigned to the highest quantile. In that way, we will not have NAs. This is my trial but I get NAs.

```
result <- cut(vec2, breaks=quantile(vec1,probs = seq(0, 1, length = 11), na.rm=T, 
type=2),include.lowest=T)

as.data.frame(cbind(vec2,result))
```

In other words, I want the lower bounds and upper bounds of the lowest and highest breaks to be -infinity and infinity.

The expected output should be like this:

```
vec2 result
1    -5       1
2    -4       1
3    -3       1
4    -2       1
5    -1       1
6     0       1
7     1       1
8     2       1
9     3       3
10    4       4
11    5       5
12    6       7
13    7       8
14    8       9
15    9      10
16   10      10
17   11      10
18   12      10
```

Comment: What is your expected output? You can use `findInterval(vec2, vec1)`

Comment: @RonakShah
The expected deciles for vec2 should be like this:  
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
10
10

Comment: Please update your post with the expected output. Why there are 7 1's in the beginning `vec1` has breaks at 0 and 1.

Comment: Why is `result2` 1 for `vec2` ?

Comment: It's my first time posting so I may have made a few mistakes here and there. I have corrected them.

Comment: It's ok but you are still not clarifying what I have been asking you. Why `vec2` 1 and 2 has `result` 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for

```
ifelse(vec2 < min(vec1), min(vec1), ifelse(vec2 > max(vec1), max(vec1), vec2))
#> [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 10 10
```

I note this doesn't quite match your example output, but it seems to fit your description of what you're trying to do. You appear to have made a couple of mistakes in the example. It could be modified easily enough if you need to change the output.